# Getting related data in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 tables  products table , images table and products_images, a product can have multiple images.
I am able to upload data and the images to database. Now I want to query data from products table and a single image for that product and display it in the view. So far I can just query the data from product table.

```
The image model
class Images extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = ['title','filename'];
 public function products(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Products::class,'products_images');
  }
```

My image path  public'\images2'

In my controller I am getting data using this function

```
 public function getproducts()
        {
           Products::latest()->paginate(5);    //only returning id,title,price, location.  I want it 
           to return an image.
    }
```

In my view

```
<div class="contents">
        <div v-for="image in images.data" :key="image.id" class="p-2">
                 <div class="item p-2">{{image.id}}</div>
                  <div class="item p-2">{{image.title}} Price:{{image.price}} </div>
                  <div class="item p-2"><p>Loc:{{image.location}}</p></div>
               //This is where  I want  to add the image here.
                 <div class="item p-2"> <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" :href="'/products/' + 
              image.id">View</a>
                 </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Do you have the images relation set in your products model? In that case you can include them by using with(): Products::latest()->with('images')->paginate(5);

Comment: v-for="image in images", but that depends on your vue components data property offcourse

Comment: But you fill the images property with you ajax call response

Comment: @GertB, I have cleared the error the problem now is getting the image using {{image.filename}} but this returns null